# Subgroup with two generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $x,y,g$ be elements in some group $G$. Is is true that $g \langle x,y, \rangle = \langle gx,gy \rangle$? Clearly $\langle gx,gy \rangle \le g \langle x,y \rangle$, since the latter contains the former's generators. However, I am having a little trouble with the other inclusion I could use a hint.

Comment: $\;\langle gx,\,gy\rangle\;$ is **always** a subgroup, whereas *the product* of subgroups $\;\langle g\rangle\,\langle x,y\rangle\;$ may not even  be a subgroup.

Comment: $x=1,y=1,g\neq 1$ yields a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $g\langle x,y\rangle$ represents the coset of $\langle x,y\rangle$, then the answer is no because $g\langle x,y\rangle$ is not a group when $g\not\in\langle x,y\rangle$, but $\langle gx,gy\rangle$ is always a group.

Following @DonAntonio's comment above, perhaps $g\langle x,y\rangle$ means $\langle g\rangle\langle x,y\rangle$, i.e., the product of groups.  This may or may not be a group, and observe also that $gxgy\in\langle gx,gy\rangle$, while the closest element in $\langle g\rangle\langle x,y\rangle$ is $g^2xy$, but these are not equal unless $g$ commutes with $x$ and $y$.

Your statement $\langle gx,gy\rangle\subseteq g\langle x,y\rangle$ does not follow because while $gx,gy\in g\langle x,y\rangle$, $g\langle x,y\rangle$ is not a group, so containing the generators isn't enough to say anything.

Comment: ...Of course...thanks!

Comment: A follow up question (or maybe what was meant in the first place) might be: What about $<g<x,y>>$ and $<gx, gy>$?

Comment: @cdwe Let $H=\langle g\langle x,y\rangle\rangle$ observe $H\subseteq\langle g,x,y\rangle$.  On the other hand, note that $g\in H$ (and so $g^{-1}\in H$) since $e\in\langle x,y\rangle$.  Therefore, $g,x,y\in H$, so $H=\langle g,x,y\rangle$.